# Geolocation API Permissions Web Browser

Tags: html, api, browser, geolocation

I'm using this code to get the user geoposition. All goes well until the user deny permission to get the location. It seems this option gets cached and I don't know how reset it.

Is there any way to re-ask permission? Thanks in advance!

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {                                            

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {       

            // Success Callback


        }, function(error) {
            //error Callback

        },{
                  //options
            });
     }else{
        //geolocation not available
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is a browser/device setting stored per site.  I think the point is that you can't reset this from a script as it would defeat the point of the prompt in the first place.  I believe the only way to reset is to change the setting in the browser/device.

Answer (score 1):

Like bgreater said, it depends on browser. But when user deny permission to get location error function will be called with error object. This error object contains error code. When error code equals 1 it means that user deny permission.

```
var errorTypes = {
    0: "Unknown error",
    1: "Permission denied by user",
    2: "Position is not available",
    3: "Request timed out" 
};
```

I think, you can check this error code and display some kind of information to user.